# asp.net mvc validations on runtime generated fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-validation

I am creating a form in which some `HTML` fields are getting generated at runtime based on database values and then I want to add validation to them. My current scene is like this:

Model:

```
public class MeasureModel
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Measure Name")]
    public int? MeasureName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DisplayName("Install Date")]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? InstallDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<Datapoint> Datapoints { get; set; }
}

public class Datapoint
{
    public string DatapointTypeName { get; set; }

    public string DatapointTypeLabel { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public string ValidationRule { get; set; }

}
```

My view is like this:

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JobCost)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JobCost)
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Datapoints.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Model.Datapoints[i].DatapointTypeLabel
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Datapoints[i].DatapointTypeName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Datapoints[i].Value)
        </div>
    }
```

I loop through datapoints to generate textbox for each datapoint. Each of these datapoints have different validation rules associated with them like `RequiredText`, `RequiredDecimal`, `Range(10, 100)`, etc. For implementing validation I tried creating Custom `ModelValidatorProvider` as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463900/Creating-a-custom-ModelValidatorProvider-in-ASP-NE).

Validations as described here work great for normal model fields but in case of datapoints, for which textfields get generated dynamically this doesn't works.

Reason for validations not getting picked is `modelMetadata` isn't getting picked properly for dynamic fields and I don't get metadata propertyName in method `GetValidators` of class `XmlModelValidatorProvider` as described in link I mentioned.

I am sure that what I am trying to achieve is a common sort of requirement and `MVC` must have some better way to achieve this,  but am not sure if what I am trying is right or plain stupid.

Please suggest what's mistake in my current approach or some other approach that suits this case.

Edit:

Adding a little info about validation provider class that I have currently:

```
    public class XmlModelValidatorProvider : ModelValidatorProvider
    {
    public readonly Dictionary<string, Type> _validatorTypes;

    ...
    public override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
           {
            ....
    }
```

more details of this class can be [found here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463900/Creating-a-custom-ModelValidatorProvider-in-ASP-NE)